Effortless automated proofs for "simple" formulae?
From small cases to all of them. This is in the spirit of 15 theorem see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_and_290_theorems
EXAMPLE : Suppose you have the following problem: P(a)
For any fixed non negative integer $a$ define the relation
$R_a :\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{0,1\}  $ as  $ R_a(i,j)=1$ if $ i\leq Min(a,j)$ else $0$.
Do we have $ \forall  (i,j,k)  R_a(i,j).R_a(j,k) <= R_a(i,k)$ ?
You may of course show by hand that $R_a$ is transitive. You may also test it by computer for all quadruples $(a,i,j,k)$ in some TEST_SPACE like [0,10]x[1,1000]x[1,1000]x[1,1000].
If the test is positive I think most people are convinced that P(a) is true for any $a$.
Mainly because we use 3 variables(i,j,k) and one parameter (a) , and addition(+) and compare (<=) and Min.
QUESTION: Are there any theorem saying that if the size of TEST_SPACE is at least above a bound function of the formula length,depth,number of variables(...) then truth on TEST_SPACE implies truth everywhere.
a) Assume there are only Min,Max , add , substract , comparison , small constants ,only integers (non negative?) , and a small number of variables ( says < 10).
NOTE1 : I guess some terribly high bound does exist BUT the theorem should be useful that is I don't want triple exponential bound ,( says one exponential at most )
Concrete answers or domain direction will be appreciated.

You seem to be asking about the size of a minimal counterexample to a universal sentence of Presburger arithmetic, or equivalently, of a minimal solution of an integer linear program. These are known to have bit-length polynomial in the length of the formula.

@Emil Jeřábek : Taking a quick look at Pressburger Arith : Is the degree of polynomial constructive, and I am not sure how to cover Min(i,j) or Max() ?

$\min$ and $\max$ are quantifier-free definable from order: e.g., $\min(x,y)=z\iff(x\le y\land z=x)\lor(y\le x\land z=y)$. The bounds are explicit, and the exponent should be something small (2 or 3 or so), but I can’t search the literature now.

@Emil Jeřábek : Very clear, thank you.
